# The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=4.2.3 and <4.3.0 but 4.4.0-dev.20210724 was found instead

Tags: angular

The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=4.2.3 and <4.3.0 but 4.4.0-dev.20210724 was found instead.
I have understood one thing that whenever error like this occurs you should type this command:

```
npm i -D typescript@4.2.6
```

You should keep guessing the right number between 4.2.3 and 4.3.0 I got 4.2.4 as a correct guess.

Comment: please update your question with some more information like your package.json and details you see when doing ng --version

Comment: You do not have to guess the version, go to your package repository, if you use the default go to https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript click the versions tab and that shows you all available versions for the package 'typescript'.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are using the latest angular version.

If this is not worked in your case    `"npm i -D typescript@4.2.6"`,
Try this.

1. `npm install typescript@'>==4.2.3 <4.3.0'`
   or `npm install typescript@'>==4.2.3 <4.3.0' --save-dev`
2. Go to package.json and change your typescript version in dev dependencies,

   "devDependencies": {
   ...
   "typescript": "~4.2.5"
   }